# Parsing string generating my generated error message when nothing is entered

Tags: java, string, parsing, while-loop

I am currently working on an assignment to parse strings and I am running into an issue.

It appears, that if nothing is entered, it is generating my error message I have created when a comma is not inputted.

According to the assignment in zybooks, it should not be outputting anything. Below is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseStrings {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);  // scanner for input

      //local variables
      String lineString;
      String firstWord;
      String secondWord;
      int commaLocation;
      boolean inputDone;

      //checks to end the program
      inputDone = false;

      //keeps the loop running until q is entered      
      while (!inputDone)  {
         System.out.println("Enter input string: ");
         lineString = scnr.nextLine();

         //checks comma
         commaLocation = lineString.indexOf(',');

         if (commaLocation == -1)  {
            System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");
         }

         else  {
         firstWord = lineString.substring(0, commaLocation);
         firstWord = firstWord.replace(" ", "");

         secondWord = lineString.substring(commaLocation + 1, lineString.length());
         secondWord = secondWord.replace(" ", "");

         System.out.println("First word: " + firstWord);
         System.out.println("Second word: " + secondWord);

         System.out.println();
         System.out.println();

         }

         if (lineString.equals("q"))   {
            inputDone = true;

         }



      }



      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because when nothing is entered, comma cannot be found, therefore `indexOf` returns -1.

I would add something like

```
if (lineString.isEmpty()) {
    continue;
}
```

right after `lineString = scnr.nextLine();`

EDIT:
I just noticed, that your error message will be printed in case, when your input equals 'q'. I assume this is not an expected behaviour, so I recommend to place

```
if (lineString.equals("q")) {
    inputDone = true;
}
```

right after assignment of `lineString` or the `if` block I suggested above.